# Content of ContentControl in Resource

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a ContentControl in a RadTileView. If I put in some hard coded text into the content property it works fine. (code below)

```
 <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Hello World"></ContentControl>
```

That works...if I put the content into the UserControl.Resources section my application freezes up and displays nothing.

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="{StaticResource TabControlContent}"></ContentControl>

<UserControl.Resources>
        <TextBlock x:Key="TabControlContent" Text="hello world"></TextBlock>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Ultimately I would like to have the context be a RadTabControl..but for now Id settle on just having that textblock render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a string into your ContentControl you would, add

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

to your usings. Then add this

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <sys:String x:Key="SingleString">Hello World</sys:String>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Which would allow

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource SingleString}}"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok..I will try this..ultimately I need to add this instead of a textblock..<UserControl.Resources>
        <telerik:RadTabControl x:Key="TabControlContent" Margin="4" Name="DynamicTabs" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">            
        </telerik:RadTabControl>
    </UserControl.Resources> - i see where you're going a bit though so i will try it down this path...

Comment: Rus..the code above worked perfectly..now im going to try to do this with that telerik radtabcontrol...

Comment: If you're using a MVVM approach in your project I would consider wrapping your RadTabControl up in a UserControl with its own viewModel, keeping the composition of your views outside your XAML markup.